# Confusion matrix giving me "all arguments must have the same length" error?

Tags: r, tree, statistics, analytics, confusion-matrix

I'm getting an error that says "Error in table(pre2020$combined_status, pred.rpart) :
all arguments must have the same length" for the following code that I wrote. I'm trying to evaluate a regression tree I wrote. How can I solve this error?

```
library(rpart)
n = nrow(pre2020)
train = sample(n, n/2)
rpart.pre2020 <- rpart(combined_status ~ . - person_id, data = pre2020,
                       subset = train)
summary(rpart.pre2020) 
pred.2020 = predict(rpart.pre2020)
table(pre2020$combined_status, pred.rpart)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table(pred.2020, pre2020$combined_status[train])
```

```
pred.2020   0   1
        0 259   0
        1   0 241
```

Or using the caret package:

```
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(pred.2020, pre2020$combined_status[train])
```

Example output:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 259   0
         1   0 241
                                     
               Accuracy : 1          
                 95% CI : (0.9926, 1)
    No Information Rate : 0.518      
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  
                                     
                  Kappa : 1          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         
                                     
            Sensitivity : 1.000      
            Specificity : 1.000      
         Pos Pred Value : 1.000      
         Neg Pred Value : 1.000      
             Prevalence : 0.518      
         Detection Rate : 0.518      
   Detection Prevalence : 0.518      
      Balanced Accuracy : 1.000      
                                     
       'Positive' Class : 0
```